# AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter, and am having an issue when submitting the code. I had an error before involving the reset button, but that has since been fixed, but now the code does not submit, giving the error that is in the title

Here is the code in its entirety https://pastecord.com/ujoxixyhob.dpr

I dont think this will help too much, so here I have isolated it to this one part:

```
def Submit():
        name = entry_name.get()
        residency = ''
        if rbtnValue.get() == 'intl':
            residency = 'intl'
        if rbtnValue.get() == 'dom':
            residency = 'dom'

        program = comboProgramming.get()
        
        courses = ''
        if cbtnProgramming.get() == 'COMP100':
            courses += '(COMP100)'
        if cbtnWebDesign.get() == 'COMP213':
            courses += '\n(COMP213)'
        if cbtnSoftEng.get() == 'COMP120':
            courses += '\n(COMP120)'
        result = name + '\n' + program + '\n' + residency + '\n' + courses
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Information', message=result)
```

This is where the error says it is. I am hoping to find out the error. Thank you

Comment: You retrieve the state of a Checkbutton by calling `.get()` on the Var attached to it, rather than the widget itself.

Comment: odd. that is what I am doing

Comment: You assigned every single one of your Checkbuttons to the same name as its Var - thus losing access to the Var.  Note that you normally don't need to assign a Checkbutton to a name at all - the exception would be if you intended to change its text, color, etc. later.

Comment: So what would fix it then?

Comment: I want to apologize. I have solved this error. I will write the solution here. Thank you for your help